# Unable to access values from the old map

Tags: apex, map, sobject

Currently, I'm trying to get values from an old map because currently, my map is like `Map <Id, Sobject>`

It's showing an error like

> Variable does not exist: ARPU__C

I'm unable to fetch data from this line oldItems.get(i.id).ARPU__C

```
public void AfterUpdate(Map<Id, SObject> newItems, Map<Id, SObject> oldItems) 
    {
        Id recordTypeId = [Select Id From RecordType Where DeveloperName = 'Customer_Order' Limit 1].Id;
        Id recordTypeId1 = [Select Id From RecordType Where DeveloperName = 'UBI_Fulfillment' Limit 1].Id;
        for(Case i:(List<case>)newItems.values())
        {
            if(i.ARPU__c != oldItems.get(i.id).ARPU__C && i.RecordTypeId == recordTypeId || i.RecordTypeId == recordTypeId1 && (i.Case_Details__c =='New Subscription' || i.Case_Details__c =='Add On') )
            {
            }
        }
```

As per Adrian Larson inputs, I have updated my code like below

```
Map<Id, Case> OldRecords = new Map<Id, Case>();
        for(Id key : oldItems.keySet())
        {
            OldRecords.put(key, (Case)oldItems.get(key));
        }
```

Please let me know whether is it a best practice to typecast like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't statically reference fields from a generic `SObject`. Either Change from `Map<Id, SObject>` to `Map<Id, Case>`, or use dynamic `get`. The former option is much preferred and will have better performance.

Instead of:

```
public void AfterUpdate(Map<Id, SObject> newItems, Map<Id, SObject> oldItems)
```

Use:

```
public void AfterUpdate(Map<Id, Case> newItems, Map<Id, Case> oldItems)
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the explanation . But I'm not getting any idea to typecast from Map<Id, Sobject> to Map<Id, case>. Currently, I'm able to get values from the list like List<case> Oldetails = (List<Case>) oldItems.values(); but it's not usefull in my case

Comment: I have Updated my question

Comment: Just change the type of your parameters.

Comment: Sorry, my question has been updated just now. I can able to change parameters but I don't want to do that because I want to use reuse the same interface for multiple times

Comment: Each implementation should be type specific. It is much faster. I am telling you, this approach is best practice.